# Does WSDL need any changes when applying MTOM to a web service?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, mtom

So, let's assume I have a simple web service in which I am not using attachments. And then I would like to start sending attachements via MTOM. Do I need to change anything in a WSDL file? As far as I know I don't have to make changes there, but I would like to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have found this [instruction](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html) and there is a paragraph 1a) Modifying your schema for MTOM and it seems that there is only one optional change. It is to add `xmime:expectedContentTypes` parameter to field which data is to be sent as an attachment. It is optional and it tells JAXB which type of data is expected in this attachment and JAX-WS web service receives this attachment in corresponding Java type.